# System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout.AddDrawerListener' not found

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

First I started developing Android with C# and Xamarin a week ago, and I'm stuck in this problem.

I already found several texts in Stack Overflow, but sadly didn't work.

To solve this problem, I took some steps.

1. Before following things, when I start debug with `Android_Accelerated_x86` *(Android 6.0 -API 23)*, Visual Studio start find `NavigationPageRenderer` but is not there then I got message title above
2. I installed and updated Packages using Android SDK Manager like following
3. Then, I met message wrote on title

   ```
   System.MissingMethodException: Method
   Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout.AddDrawerListener' not found
   ```

   So, I struggled to find solution and

   1. I downloaded *JDK 1.8.0_101* and changed path of Java Development Kit Location (in Tools > Option > Xamarin > Android Setting) but it didn't work. I've got the same message like title above.
   2. I went to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution and updated only *Xamarin.Forms v2.3.2.127*. Then I got 7 errors. One of them is

      > **Error:** package `android.support.v7.internal.widget` does not exist.
4. And I deleted the solution and make new project with Xamarin.Forms I got the Warnings message like

   > **IDE0006 Error encountered** while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled

   and... I got the message like title above.
5. Also I got two 'Call Stack'

   ```
   0x23 in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.OnAttachedToWindow at NavigationPageRenderer.cs

   0xA in Android.Views.View.n_OnAttachedToWindow at Android.Views.View.cs:
   ```

Please help me to solve this problem... Thanks a lot for your attention

Comment: oh god... i got answer!  from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546360/xamarin-forms-missingmethodexception-android-support-v4-widget-drawerlayout-ad

after updating **Xamarin.Forms v2.3.2.127**, still **packages.config** didn't updated

then i wrote manually and it work!!!!!

Comment: Yup installing Xamarin.Forms v2.3.2.127 solved it for me also!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue happens because Google changed their support libraries in which you hookup this listener from `SetDrawerListener()` to `AddDrawerListener()`. Because of this you will need to ensure you're on the latest stable Xamarin.Forms. Previous versions of Xamarin.Forms that have a dependency on < `Android.Support` 23.3 will throw this error. You can refer to this commit for more details:

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/commit/d9ed63f0add8345cf6ab1508b353dcbdacbcd97c

Ideally this should be fixed in Xamarin.Forms versions 2.2.0.31 and greater.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/